# The installer doesn't start

Tags: installation

I downloaded ubuntu-12.04-desktop-i386.iso and burned it onto a CD. That went fine. I started my notebook from the CD and that went fine too.

After a while I get a screen with the Launcher at the left side of the screen. The second icon from the top is "Install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS". I double-click it, but nothing happens. At the right side, there's a separate "Install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS" icon. I double-click it, but again nothing happens.

Should I be doing something else to install Ubuntu on the harddrive? Btw, the notebook is an Asus EEE 901 with a solid state harddrive.

Thanks!

Comment: For me it took about 5-10 minutes before the installer finally loaded.  Give it some more time and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks Corey and Zeferino. When I double-click the "Install" button, nothing happens, even if I wait more than 10 minutes. (The CD drive doesn't even speed up.) If I start one of the other applications, the CD drive speeds up right away and the requested application starts. Right now Fedora Linux 17 is installed on the solid state drive. Is it possible that Ubuntu thinks it's already installed so it simply doesn't start the installation? (I couldn't find a utility in Ubuntu to remove the current partitions to test this.)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's running off of CD, it can take a little while for it to load up. Did you give it enough time to load?

Answer (score 0):

Try burning it onto a DVD if you can.

Comment: @tijybba This is definitely an attempt to answer the question; Zeferino is saying that Bob should try burning the ISO image to a DVD rather than CD. An answer does not cease to be an answer *just* by being short. Furthermore, [even answers that do not contain enough information are not generally appropriate as comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments), though sometimes they can be deleted.

Comment: Yes you are right , i stopped reviewing couple of days ago , it is not as easy as i thought , sorry @zeferino for posting the wrong comment i will +1 it :)